# How to get a dynamic attribute name in cfloop over query in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfloop

I'm inside a `cfloop` over a query. I want to get an attribute, but I won't know what that attribute will be until runtime. Using `#qryResult[MyAttr]#` fails with the error "Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values."  What is the syntax for doing this?

Here is a simplified example:

```
<cfquery datasource="TestSource" name="qryResult">
    SELECT * FROM MyTable
</cfquery>

<cfloop query="qryResult">
    <cfset MyAttr="autoid" />
    <cfoutput>
        Test 1: #qryResult.autoid# <br/>  <!--- succeeds --->
        Test 2: #qryResult[MyAttr]# <br/> <!--- fails --->
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<cfloop query="qryResult">
  <cfset MyAttr="autoid" />
  <cfoutput>
   Test 1: #qryResult.autoid# <br/>  <!--- succeeds --->
   Test 2: #qryResult[MyAttr][qryResult.CurrentRow]# <br/> <!--- succeeds --->
  </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

`CurrentRow` is implicit in the literal syntax (`query.col`). It is tied to the index of `<cfloop query="...">`/`<cfoutput query="...">` (or 1 when used outside a loop).

Mentioning it explicitly is necessary in the "array index" syntax (`query[col][row]`), because `query[col]` alone returns the column object (which is the "complex type" the error refers to).

Side effect: You can use this for random access to a query result outside of a loop (i.e. as a multi-dimensional array). Once you know the numbers of the rows that interest you, you can access the rows directly.