# Using column names from dynamically named variables in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfquery, dynamic-variables, cfloop

I want to create a function that will loop through an arbitrary query and perform an insert into another table based on the arbitrary column names.

For instance, the idea here would be to output

```
(data, data, data...)
(data, data, data...)
```

Ultimately, I'm going to do an insert query. For now, I just want to output the rows.

**EDIT:** I can't just do an `INSERT/SELECT` because the prod data and dev data are on different servers. So I have to first collect the data from the table on the prod server into a CF query object, and then loop through it and insert into the table on the dev server.

**Code:**

```
<cffunction name="copyProdToDev">

    <cfargument name="devDatasource" >
    <cfargument name="prodDataSource" type="string">
    <cfargument name="devTableName" type="string">
    <cfargument name="prodTableName" type="string">
    <cfargument name="dateColumnName" default="none">

    <cfquery name="ProdData" datasource="#prodDatasource#" timeout="60">
        SELECT *
        FROM #prodTableName#
    </cfquery>

    <cfset columnNames = ProdData.getColumnNames()> 
    <cfset numColumns = ArrayLen(columnNames)>

    <cfloop query="#ProdData#">
        (
        <cfloop index="colNumber" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(columnNames)-1#">
            <cfoutput><dynamic column name for colNumber>,</cfoutput>
        </cfloop>
        <cfoutput><dynamic column name for numColumns></cfoutput>
        )<br />
    </cfloop>

</cffunction>
```

Comment: While it is possible, can you not just insert the data directly with an INSERT/SELECT ...? Is the target table structure the same?

Comment: There is. It's because the production data and the dev data are on different servers. So, I cant just do `insert into a select * from b`. I'll update my question to reflect that.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? SQL Server will allow you to link servers, so you can run a query on one that will retrieve data in another.

Comment: @ScottStroz We are not allowed to have linked servers here :(. Tight security.

Comment: But you can pull data into a 3rd system that functions as the 'link'? Seems counter productive.

Comment: It's a DOE facility. I have no control over the servers. And never shall they meet. Dan Bracuk's answer does solve the problem.

Comment: *And never shall they meet* That is putting it mildly, I am sure ;-) BTW, getColumnNames() is an undocumented method. Unfortunately, there is no direct alternative last I checked, but you can do the same thing with `getMetaData(queryName)`.  The function returns an array of structures.  The column name is under the "name" key.  Using an array loop, ie `currentArrayElement.name`

Comment: @Leigh -- what makes this a different question is that in the other post (which I did find), it was not explicitly shown that the column loop is inside a query loop. I was unsure of how they were getting the object called `query`. Actually, I did just notice this, which mine is pretty much a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581394/how-to-get-a-dynamic-attribute-name-in-cfloop-over-query-in-coldfusion?rq=1 if you put the two together -- the query loop and then the nested column loop.

Comment: They don't 'meet' except where the ColdFusion connects them. ;-)

Comment: @abalter -  Yes, this question comes up pretty frequently, so there are a *lot* of threads on it, all with minor variations (all essentially doing the same thing:  loop through query + column list/array). That was just the thread I happened to pick.  Ultimately, the solution was what is in the link - ie "use array notation". Since you already had both the column names - and the inner loop - it seemed like you already had the rest figured out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Array notation is your friend.

```
<cfoutput>
<cfloop query = "ProdData">
<cfloop array = "#ProdData.getColumnList()#" index = columnName>
#prodData[columnName][currentrow]#
closing tags and formatting stuff
```

Comment: Bingo! Didn't know that `cfloop` had `currentrow`.

Comment: Technically, it's `cfquery` that has currentrow.

Comment: That's what I thought. However, I was able to access `currentrow` inside a `<cfloop query=...`. That was news to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the list from this variable

```
ProdData.columnList
```

But be aware that the order of the columns is not totally respected, 
this article might help: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/644-query-columnlist-does-not-return-true-column-ordering.htm

Comment: You can get them in the correct order by using `getColumnNames` as I did in my code. I believe that is since CF 8 or so. http://www.richarddavies.us/archives/2009/07/cf_columnlist.php

Comment: Ok I am sorry. So your difficulty is getting the value of the columns, is it? If so, you can use the evaluate function: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f4e.html   and do something like Evaluate("ProdData.#columnNames[colNumber]#")

Comment: Evaluate does work, but id widely cautioned against.

Comment: Well, idk if this works, but have tried looping the query using index and getting your value like this: ProdData["#columnNames[colNumber]#"][i] .You would have to loop using a index from 1 to the recordCount instead of looping the query. I am not sure it would work.